# How do I connect to a remote Neo4j database using gremlin python?

Tags: python, neo4j, gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlinpython

From what I've read Neo4j implements apache tinkerpop which leads me to think I can use gremlin python and rather than connect to a gremlin server I can point the python code at a neo4j server and treat it like a gremlin server.

However I can't find any information online which shows how to do this so I'm thinking maybe I've misunderstood something.

- a) Can I use gremlin python directly with a neo4j db instance?
- b) If
  yes to (a) then how?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 5):

You can not connect `gremlin-python` to Neo4j Server. `gremlin-python` contains drivers that connect to Gremlin Server so you must have that installed for `gremlin-python` to work. Given that you need Gremlin Server you must choose one of the following options all of which are just Gremlin Server configurations:

1. Configure Neo4j in [embedded mode](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-embedded) within Gremlin Server. An example of this is [here](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/f799335a29e5da98644b75e8d5d9aea810bc6262/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml#L33) where that file points to a Neo4j [configuration file](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/f799335a29e5da98644b75e8d5d9aea810bc6262/gremlin-server/conf/neo4j-empty.properties). Note that these files are packaged in the Gremlin Server distribution as samples so you can run them directly quite easily.
2. Modify the aforementioned Neo4j configuration file to [run Neo4j in HA mode](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_high_availability_configuration) effectively turning Gremlin Server into a node in the Neo4j cluster.
3. Configure a [neo4j-gremlin-bolt](https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt) instance which will use the Neo4j Bolt protocol to connect to the running Neo4j Server. While I"m not completely familiar with this implementation, I can see that you would change the `gremlin.graph` to `com.steelbridgelabs.oss.neo4j.structure.Neo4JGraph` and that you would discern Bolt configuration options from [this class](https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt/blob/df3ab429e0c83affae6cd43d41edd90de80c032e/src/main/java/com/steelbridgelabs/oss/neo4j/structure/Neo4JGraphFactory.java) (which instantiates that graph instance).

Once you've chosen one of those configuration options you can then use `gremlin-python` to work with Neo4j.

Comment: how can I work with Neo4J in Gremlin and Python then? I've tried to find but there aren't any guides on this topic. After starting an instance running Neo4J, how can I run Gremlin queries on it in Python?

Comment: i've tried to improve the answer a bit. hope that clarifies things.

Comment: @stephenmallette Can you provide detailed information on point 2 and 3 suggested by you if possible?

Comment: there's not much more detail. i mean, in point 1 i point you to a configuration file for embedded mode. you modify that configuration file as needed for points 2 and 3. for point 2, the configuration example in the link i provided. for point 3 you'd have to consult that project's documentation as i'm not familiar with its exact configuration options but I updated my answer with some extra tips to get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I have downvoted this answer since i did not find any concrete implementation out there see e.g.  https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt/issues/71  or https://community.neo4j.com/t/neo4j-gremlin-integration/8144 and yes personally i think *a lot more detail* is needed to get this working